# Change the behavior of a column to wrap content with width of longest row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im a new user to bootstrap and trying to use the grid system for my needs.
I find it very annoying that sometimes the column width is too long, and the spacing between the columns (as a result of the 12 columns grid system) is too much.
Since the page is responsive it makes it even harder to find a workaround.

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">A</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1"><img src="..." class="img-responsive" /></div>
            <div class="col-xs-9">C</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is your question mate? you can customize grid system in bootstrap, http://getbootstrap.com/customize/, instead 12 columns you can use a less number

Comment: Yes, but it wont really solve the problem. I want to be able to make a column width to be the max-width of the rows in it. dynamically, which is the bahvior of a regular, most simple <table> in html. How can I add this behavior for only a single column?

Comment: maybe you can modify the mixins, see this https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap (bootstrap code), in my project we have cloned this repo and we have modified bootstrap code to satisfy our needs